# Could not find default endpoint element error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, dotnetnuke

I am getting below error while consuming a WCF service. I have developed a wcf service which is being consumed by a usercontrol.And user control is used as module in DNN.

But if i simply consume the wcf in web application it is working fine but consuming in DNN module is giving below error

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'OperationService.IOperation' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Please advise.

Client side config is below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IOperation" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:54147/WCFService/Service.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IOperation"
            contract="OperationService.IOperation" name="WSHttpBinding_IOperation">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Added service config of wcf service from comment**

```
<system.serviceModel> 
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Operation"> 
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                contract="IOperation">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/> 
        </identity> 
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange"/> 
    </service> 
  </services>
  <behaviors> 
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior"> 
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> 
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/> 
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors> 
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: You may have incorrect configuration on WCF consumer side, post app.config/web.config from your consumer.

Comment: Is this the **server-side** config (where the WCF service is hosted), or your **client-side** config of code trying to use the service? What does the service contract look like?

Comment: I have edited the question to reply ur questions

Comment: Please post the `<system.serviceModel>` section from the service's config file.

Comment: <system.serviceModel>
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Operation">
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IOperation"><identity><dns value="localhost"/>
</identity>
</endpoint><endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/> </service> </services><behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors><behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
</behavior></serviceBehaviors></behaviors></system.serviceModel>

Answer (score 1):

copy the  section from the app.config to your site's web.config. you may need to change the endpoint's address attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The contract name needs to be fully qualified (namespace + name) in the `<endpoint>` element, like this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
          contract="OperationService.IOperation">
```

Also, make sure that the name attribute in the `<service>` element matches the name attribute in the .svc file markup.

Comment: name attribute in the <service> element is same as the name attribute in the .svc also contract name is fully qualified in client config.

Comment: @user3068811 - but it's not fully-qualified in your service's config file, which may very well be causing the issue.